# Clips matching expression is not working

Tags: expert-system, clips

hello in clips i have this template:

```
(deftemplate cell(slot x)(slot y)(slot alive))
```

and this fact :

```
(start 1 1)
```

then i have this claus in the LHS :

```
?start<-(start ?x ?y)
```

and i want to get the variable `?a1`

```
(cell (x (+ ?x 1) )(y ?y)(alive ?a1))
```

it seems that it's not allowed to add to the variable `"(+ ?x 1)"` so how 
can i achieve what i want.

Comment: By marking sections as code, using the "Code Sample" button, you can make your post more legible.

Answer (score 1):

```
CLIPS> (deftemplate cell (slot x) (slot y) (slot alive)) 
CLIPS>  
(deffacts initial
    (start 1 1)
    (cell (x 2) (y 1) (alive yes)))
CLIPS>     
(defrule example
    (start ?x ?y)
    (cell (x =(+ ?x 1)) (y ?y) (alive ?a1))
    =>
    (printout t "?a1 = " ?a1 crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
?a1 = yes
CLIPS>
```